# Finding the difference in an array

Tags: python, arrays, structure

Here is the link to the original question: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-difference/

Here is my code. I keep getting an "index out of range" error but I am not sure why.

```
class Solution:
    def findTheDifference(self, s: str, t: str) -> str:
        i = 0 
        ss = list(s)
        tt = list(t)
        while ss[i] == tt[i]: 
            i += 1 
            if ss[i] != tt[i]:
                return tt[i]
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: You loop until you find a different value - or you go further than the end of the lists... As a side note, you can do that directly on strings, no need to convert them to lists.

Comment: set(t)-set(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you give these 2 as inputs

```
s = "abcd"
t = "abcde"
```

on the 4th circle of your loop i=3 and it will become 4 since `ss[i] != tt[i]` is false it 
will go on on the next circle and will evaluate  this expression `ss[i] == tt[i]`
and ss's length is 4 and it will try to access the 5th element which doesnt exist and it eventually will throw an indexError
you could try something like:

```
class Solution:
def findTheDifference(self, s: str, t: str) -> str:
    i = 0 
    ss = list(s)+[None]
    tt = list(t)
    while ss[i] == tt[i]: 
        i += 1 
        if ss[i] != tt[i]:
            return tt[i]
```

Comment: what is the +[none] part. are you just adding one extra index to the array?

Comment: Yes it makes both ss and tt of the same size and it wont throw an error

Answer (score 1):

According to the question, string *t* will have length 1 greater than the length of string *s*. Now imagine what happens when, lets say, string *t* is formed by appending random character to end of string *s*.

When you have finished processing all of string *s*'s characters, you will proceed to check the last character of string *t*, but the character at corresponding index in string *s* is not present, and that leads to `Index Out Of Range`

There is a better approach to solve this question, try harder.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you don't stop iterating when you get to the end of the list. If you change your while condition to:

```
while ss[i] == tt[i] and i < len(ss) and i < len(tt)
```

you will avoid the `IndexError`.

Separately, this situation is much better suited for a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(min(len(ss), len(tt))):  # Only loop while both lists still have elements
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your params have a different size.

Like `t` is `abcd` and `s` is `aa` this is the reason why are you having this issue.

Lets assume that `i` is 2

`ss` will be `c` and `tt` will throw `index out of range`

`ss[i] == tt[i]`